# Import errors with python -m but not when running directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I'm trying to get my basic Flask app bundled up properly with `setup.py` for running with `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` on Python 3.6.6.

```
mygame/games/board.py
mygame/games/game.py
mygame/games/__init__.py
mygame/__init__.py
setup.py
```

If I run `__init__.py` from within the `mygame` directory everything works fine.

If I try running using `python -m mygame` it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "mygame/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from games.errors import GameCommandError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'games'
```

What's going on here?

What import scheme should I use if I want both `python -m mygame` and `python __init__.py` to work?

If I change the imports in `__init__.py` to be explictly relative (`.games.foo`) I get this when I run `python -m mygame`:

```
No module named mygame.__main__; 'mygame' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

and when I run `__init__.py` I get the same(ish) thing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .games.errors import GameCommandError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.games'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Comment: this app isn’t in your path so why should it work? before when you were running it in the __init__ file it worked because the paths were relative to where you were running it from

Comment: The `No module named mygame.__main__` error message gives you a pretty big hint about how to fix it, no? :)